# Elastic Search Score Calculations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I am migrating from ES 1.7 to ES 6.5. The data sources is common but when I search any particular keyword it returned different scores and resulting into returning different set as one with max score is selected.

I used '**_explain**' in elastic to understand the query score calculation details. I have shared query and explanation for same keyword in both the index.

**Query used :**

```
{
  "explain": true,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "search": {
            "query": "san"
          }
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "related.score"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1
}
```

**Mappings for ES 1.7**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "path": "search"
    },
    "properties": {
        "related": {
            "properties": {
                "category": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "score": {
                    "type": "double"
                },
                "search": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "search": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "english"
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation for Query in ES 1.7 :**

```
{
  "_explanation": {
    "value": 4.83643,
    "description": "function score, product of:",
    "details": [
      {
        "value": 4.8384395,
        "description": "weight(search:san in 11405) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
        "details": [
          {
            "value": 4.8384395,
            "description": "fieldWeight in 11405, product of:",
            "details": [
              {
                "value": 1,
                "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                "details": [
                  {
                    "value": 1,
                    "description": "termFreq=1.0"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "value": 4.8384395,
                "description": "idf(docFreq=1072, maxDocs=49844)"
              },
              {
                "value": 1,
                "description": "fieldNorm(doc=11405)"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": 0.99958473,
        "description": "Math.min of",
        "details": [
          {
            "value": 0.99958473,
            "description": "field value function: (doc['related.score'].value * factor=1.0)"
          },
          {
            "value": 3.4028235e+38,
            "description": "maxBoost"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": 1,
        "description": "queryBoost"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Mappings for ES 6.5**

```
{
        “mappings”: {
            “searches”: {
                “properties”: {
                    “related”: {
                        “properties”: {
                            “category”: {
                                “type”: “long”
                            },
                            “score”: {
                                “type”: “double”
                            },
                            “search”: {
                                “type”: “text”
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    “search”: {
                        “type”: “text”,
                        “analyzer”: “english”
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Explanation for Query in ES 6.5 :**

```
{
  "_explanation": {
    "value": 5.1439505,
    "description": "function score, product of:",
    "details": [
      {
        "value": 5.1460876,
        "description": "weight(search:san in 2464) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
        "details": [
          {
            "value": 5.1460876,
            "description": "score(doc=2464,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
            "details": [
              {
                "value": 3.82669,
                "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:",
                "details": [
                  {
                    "value": 5419,
                    "description": "docFreq",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 248810,
                    "description": "docCount",
                    "details": []
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "value": 1.3447882,
                "description": "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:",
                "details": [
                  {
                    "value": 1,
                    "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 1.2,
                    "description": "parameter k1",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 0.75,
                    "description": "parameter b",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 2.679008,
                    "description": "avgFieldLength",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 1,
                    "description": "fieldLength",
                    "details": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": 0.99958473,
        "description": "min of:",
        "details": [
          {
            "value": 0.99958473,
            "description": "field value function: none(doc['related.score'].value * factor=1.0)",
            "details": []
          },
          {
            "value": 3.4028235e+38,
            "description": "maxBoost",
            "details": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If we have look on both the explanation score calculation has changed is different in both version of ES leading to different score.  **size=1** in the query hence it should return record with max score but as score calculation method changed it returns different score for same keyword in ES 1.7 and ES 6.5 resulting into different keyword with max score.

Can someone please help me to find how we can get the same scores ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several changes in these two versions and the main is how score is calculated in ES 1.7([tf/idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)) and how it's changed to [BM25](https://www.elastic.co/blog/practical-bm25-part-1-how-shards-affect-relevance-scoring-in-elasticsearch) in ES6.X.

It also depends on how many shards you have in your index. as the score is calculated is local to shard.

IMO, getting the same score in both these versions, even after a number of primary shards for huge no of documents might be really difficult. what you should aim is checking the order(ie if same document was in top 5 earlier it should still be in top 5 or 10 so) is not changed significantly for same search queries.

Comment: I am currently only using on one shard. I know as score function has changed value will vary but what is problem for me is the order has changed for few of the keywords. So few keywords got more score than the previous versions and hence they changed the order .

Comment: @RohanKadu, how many docs you have in your index? also any change in the mapping or query ?

Comment: 248810 are total number of documents and 5419 is frequency of keyword in all the documents. There is no change in query but had to change mappings.

Comment: I have updated my question and added both the mappings. Hope this will help you to get the complete picture.

Comment: @RohanKadu, `search` is your field which is storing your keywords?

Comment: Yes it is storing all the keywords ... and we are searching against it ..

Comment: hmm, lgtm as strings are replaced with `text` fields and analzer remains the same, I guess bm25 is causing the issue :)

Comment: So is there anything which can be changed to return the results in same order as it was in ES 1.7 .... is analyser needs to be changed ??

Comment: @RohanKadu no as I mentioned exact same order shouldn't be your end goal, you can just make sure that its not drastically different, maybe you are getting correct according to new BM25 algo and there is no issue

Comment: Thanks for your response. It really helped me to understand what exactly was causing the order changes. I was reading about tf/idf & BM25 and came to know the 'term frequency' is changing the score for same keyword. So if I search 'car' in ES 1.7 the search was giving more score to exact match 'car' but in ES 6.5 it gives more score to 'car in cars' as keyword is used twice. Hence changing the order. I hope I got it correctly. Thanks again :-).

Comment: @RohanKadu, great to hear back from you and thanks for kind words, comments like this give us the motivation to help the community and share the knowledge and yes, looks like you are right and got to the crux of the problem :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212692/discussion-between-rohan-kadu-and-opster-elasticsearch-ninja).